# Why does this simple transition on toggling elements with `v-if` not work?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-transitions

If i try a very simple example with two `<div>`'s, only one of which is showing at a time by using `v-if`, the `out-in` transition doesn't fade between them.

```
<div id="app">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <div v-if="(box==='a')">a</div>
    <div v-if="(box==='b')">b</div>
  </transition>

  <button @click="box='a'">show a</button>
  <button @click="box='b'">show b</button>
</div>
```

And my CSS code for the animation:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle located here: https://jsfiddle.net/3ckto1am/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **"div box"** to a **`boolean` value** & then create a method which toggles the **`boolean`** between **`true/false`** like so:

**Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <div v-if="boxA" key="boxA">Div A</div>
    <div v-else key="boxB">Div B</div>
  </transition>
  
  <button @click="toggleBoxes">Toggle div boxes!</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    boxA: true
  },
  methods: {
    toggleBoxes() {
        this.boxA = !this.boxA;
    }
  }
})
```

**Edit:**

As for the **`<transition>`**, when toggling between elements that have the same tag name, you must tell **[Vue](https://vuejs.org/)** that they are distinct elements by giving them **unique key attributes** (**`key='<uniqueKey>'`**) to the **tag elements**, you can read about it **[here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements)**.

You can check this **[working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/qaxbchrt/1/)**.

However, if you still want to have **two buttons** to toggle the **`<div>`**, check **[this code](https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/yngp1hea/)** instead.

Furthermore, I highly suggest you to read the **official documentation** on **[Conditional Rendering with Vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)**.

Comment: I don't see how that solves the transition... at least in my browser it doesn't work.